# reset pip3 installation path

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am using Mac. My pip3 installation path is `/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages`, but my python version is python3.9.[image].

Actually there is no python 3.11 in my Mac.
[image]

How could this happen？What should I do if I want to fix this problem?

Should I change the installation address to `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` or `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/pkgconfig`?

Comment: What is the problem here?  So, you don't have Python 3.11.  So what?

Comment: @TimRoberts I need pip3 to install packages under python 3.9, but now pip3 is wrongly installing all the packages to a python 3.11 folder.

Comment: Well, there certainly is some confusion, since the second image shows that `/usr/local/bin/python3` is Python 3.7.3.  You can always do `python -m pip install xxxx`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your problem is caused by having multiple versions of Python installed on your system, causing this little confusion.

To avoid this type of problem, I can suggest that you use asdf, which will manage the Python versions for you without the need to install them separately. Just follow the installation process (https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html) and use the following commands:

1. To install the Python plugin:

   ```bash
   $ asdf plugin add python
   ```
2. Install the desired version of Python (just change the version number)

   ```bash
   $ asdf install python 3.11.3
   ```

From now on, assuming you have installed all the desired Python versions, you can work with two scopes, local and global. In other words, you can define a global Python version (the Python that will be used throughout your system) or local, the Python that will be executed in the directory where the command is executed. The command to change the local and global Python versions are, respectively:

```bash
$ asdf local python 3.11.3
```

```bash
$ asdf global python 3.11.3
```

There you go, this way you should no longer have any problems with the use of multiple Python versions installed on your system.

To use Python 3.10, for example, just run the above commands in the directory where you want to use it.